# Corrupted file on some instances on Azure with php

Tags: php, azure, wincache

We're currently banging our heads against the wall with our Azure setup. It might be us who lack skills, but we cannot figure out how to run our instances more smoothly. We run `PHP 5.6` w. `wincache` on Azure. We have multiple instances, which share most of the files. However, it appears that the PHP cache is not shared, and some times when we deploy some files will magically be corrupt. For example a syntax error in a file which should not have a syntax error. This results in our platform throwing up, because, well syntax error in a file.

The only way to fix this appears to be a hard restart of our services, which takes time both in terms of the restart and warming the cache. We are trying to move away from the PHP setup, but unfortunately it's what we have currently.

Is there anyway to flush the system or specific instances without having to restart everything? It's kind of a ball toss if our release goes well or has loads of issues, which in turn makes us more hesitant to release.

Comment: How did you deploy your PHP app on Azure (Web Apps? VM? Cloud Services? something else?)?

Comment: It's deployed as an AppService

Comment: Have you tried deployment slots?

Comment: Oh this question is old. @RobSedgwick I can't even remember which part of our solution fixed this, but I'll try to see if I can make a writeup for anyone else to see. It was a mix of different rather hidden options (some not even featuring in the documentation from Microsoft)